# How to create bash alias with argument?

Tags: bash

I normally use `ps -elf | grep proceesname` to get a detailed description of the process named `processname`. I think that I have to write too much for this.

Now what i was thinking is to create a bash alias like

```
alias lsps='ps -elf | grep $1'
```

which will give the above detailed description only by using `lsps processname`.

So, my question is how do I create a bash alias which accepts an argument.

PS: I know I can write a shell script for the above task but I was just wondering how to do it with bash alias.

Comment: Aliases simply don't take arguments.

Comment: For GNU `ps` it's probably better to say `lsps () { ps -lf -C "$1" ; }`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Very simple;

```
alias lsps='ps -elf | grep'
```

Command line arguments will be added automatically to the end of the alias:

```
lsps arg1 arg2 arg3 => converted to => ps -elf | grep arg1 arg2 arg3
```

That works only when you want to add arguments to the end of alias.

If you want to get arguments of the alias inside of the expanded command line you must use functions:

For example:

```
lsps()
{
    ps -elf | grep "$1" | grep -v grep
}
```

Functions as well as aliases can be saved in your `~/.bashrc` file )or a file that is included from it):

```
$ cat /tmp/.bash_aliases
lsps()
{
    ps -elf | grep "$1" | grep -v grep
}

$ . /tmp/.bash_aliases
$
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But what if I had to give an argument.

Comment: Just use functions in that case

Comment: That is strange. May be you've added additional spaces after the function name (in its definition). I added example of usage to my answer, as you can see all works perfect.

Comment: Yes, you have to add the function; and that is all.

Comment: Still not working. Here is my [.bash_aliases](http://pastie.org/4248506) and the [error](http://pastie.org/4248511)

Comment: please, try to add `set -x` before (enable debug)

Comment: It started working automatically.

Comment: Defining a quick function that does the job:
    `function killName { local name="${1}"; if [ "$name" == "" ]; then return 1; fi; for pid in $(ps aux | grep "$name" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill $pid; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then kill -9 $pid; fi; done }`

You may then use it in bash with:

    `killName myprocessName`

Comment: Changing the syntax from "$1" to ${1} worked for me. I was using git-bash

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
alias lsps='ps -elf | grep'
```

Then you can issue this:

```
lsps processname
```